# Search log in magento

Tags: products, search, log

Does anyone know if there is some kind log or something build in to magento, where i can find the number of products that text written to the search has retrieved and when it occurred in the front end (the text with time stamp fits too). **I need to know the past queries not the future ones.** 
*I am the beginner in magento.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Magento Backend under `Reports -> Search Terms` you get a list of all the searches that were made and the amount of results the search gives.

It does not log exactly when each term was searched for, but it updates the amount of searches made for each term. So you can see how ofter a particular term was searched for and how many results were given out.

There you can also redirect a customer to a specific category or attribute filter for specific searches.

In the DB table catalogsearch_query you can also see when exactly the last search was made for a specific term.

Also, I'm not sure how you could possibly find any future search terms before they were made! =)

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what i searched, because the time stamp would have been better to point out the time the mistake took place.